# Down Side of Keeping Unused Platform Endpoints in AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification

**To keep the question short**:

Are there any down sides of keeping unused platform endpoints in AWS SNS?

**Long Story**:

We are currently storing platform endpoints ARN in database, for some reason we need to delete some of them from the database.

In this situation the ARN stored in the AWS SNS won't be deleted. Thus, these ARNs will become inaccessible, for the service won't know anything about these ARNs.

So back to the short version of the question: are there any down sides of doing so?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Maybe Endpoints with status "false" get deleted after some time by AWS?

Comment: @MarcJohnson Hello, as far as I know. There is not an actual down side to keep them in the AWS SNS according to the answer from the AWS tech support. However one should be very careful about the consistency of the data. One may create duplicated records, or different ARNs for the same device and getting pushes sent twice, etc.. We end up keep the consistency of the data. And we haven't tried the "false" status of an endpoint, so I cannot answer you 2nd question.